# Broken images using 'Custom Post Type UI' and 'Advanced Custom Fields' in Wordpress build

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have an 'apparel' section on this HTML website which I'm now converting to Wordpess.

In my design it looks like this (see below)
[Apparel section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CiI5.jpg)

but in my build it looks like this (see below)
[The actual build in wordpres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDIMs.png)

I don't think the code is the problem but here it is for reference:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'apparel', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC')); ?>

   <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-sm-30">
     <div class="blog-post">
       <div class="post-media">
         <img class="item-container" src="<?php the_field('apparel_img'); ?>"/>
       </div>
       <div class="product"><a><?php the_field('name_price');?></a></div>
     </div>
   </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

When I've used Chrome inspector to check what's happening with the images themselves it looks like other strings are being pulled in, and when I delete everything apart from the image root then the image isn't broken and works.

```
src="26, frontrunnerz black tee, black tee, , , image/png, http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/tee01.png, 300, 200, Array"
```

Appreciate your help with this please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have your ACF field of apparel_image outputting the array rather than URL? To output it in this way you'd want URL!

Or if you want control of the size of image being pulled through you could output ID from ACF and put in your template:

```
 $x = //post id;
 $s = //size string e.g. 'full';
 $image = get_field('apparel_image', $x);
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $s );
```

As a final note, the below site has their docs, which are really handy if you're trying to do something more complicated, but I'm pretty sure if you want to just output the src, you just need to change the output in your wp-admin custom field settings!

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

Comment: This is great, I was in the object rather than the URL! Argh so annoying, thanks Sam you're a diamond.